# How to write a small logger using varargs for WinCE

Tags: c, windows-ce

I am trying to do some investigation on some external hardware which doesn't have logging.
For this I am making my own small logger using varargs in C. This is my code:

```
void write(const char* msg, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, msg);

    FILE* file = fopen("/network/cewin/loggerfile.txt", "a");
    if(file != NULL)
    {
        vfprintf(file, msg, args);
        fputc('\n', file);
        fclose(file);
        va_end(args);
    }
}
```

First I test this code on Windows 7, without issue, but on WinCE the lines containing arguments are not printed.

Here is an example:

```
write("Hello World") - Works on Win 7 and WinCE
write("Hello %s", "World") - Works on Win7, not on WinCE
write("Hello %i", 5) - Works on Win7, not on WinCE
```

I am trying to understand why the last 2 lines are working on Win7 but not on WinCE. Maybe I need to use something else than `vfprintf` ?

I cannot check the return values from methods, because of HW.

Comment: If [`fopen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) fails then you should check [`errno`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) to find out what the problem was...

Comment: I don't think it fails, because if I print something like a simple string: "Hello world", it works on WinCE, the file is created, but if I print this: ("Hello %s", "World"), its not working.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: It can, it works for simple strings

Comment: `vfprintf` has a return status as well, you know. Error handling doesn't stop at checking that `file` is a valid handle.

Comment: @StoryTeller: there is no way for me to check the error, on WinCE. I run this on external tool.

Comment: The question is badly asked. Please, stop discussing, vote to close and let the OP learn how to rephrase it well enough so we all can understand what is the question about.

Comment: @Kobe - There is no way for you to write code that examines the return value of `vfprintf`?

Comment: @Kobe Comment deleted. Please modify your question and show 2 versions of your code, the one that works and the one that doesn't and for the latter explain what exactly does not work.

Comment: Like I said in my question: this works on Win 7, but not on WinCE. I am trying to find out why. But I can't check the return values, because I am not running locally, its run on a external tool, I don't have any way to check return codes from functions. Sorry if the question was asked bad.

Comment: Please vote to close and I will better rephrased it in another question.

Comment: You can just delete your own question, or take the time to improve it. No need to wait for close votes

Comment: @StoryTeller: ok, let me edit this one than.

Comment: I have edit my question. Thank you.

Comment: You can't open another file for debug output of the return values of functions?

Comment: @KevinDTimm: Unfortunately no, because from what I am seeing I can print only strings.

Comment: You should call `va_end` *outside* the if body.

Comment: @Kobe of course you can open an other file and write to it, why not??

Comment: What header files are you including?  Per [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms861409.aspx), you need stdarg.h, stdlib.h, and wtypes.h.  Also, `write` is a poor choice for your function name as [it's a POSIX standard function.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer -> I can't put code in comments - 'static' debug function, does not use varargs or vnprintf

```
void debugI(char *str, int iValue) 
{
    FILE *debugPtr = fopen ("/debugpath/debugFile.txt", "a");
    fprintf (debugPtr, "debugI %s:%d\n", str, iValue);
    fclose (debugPtr);
}
```